# multiCurl with Generators in Python

Tags: python, curl, generator

To be frank, I am quite new to Python.
I did go through official documentation several times.
I didn't get everything I want to know about generators in Python.

Here is what I wanted to learn.

I don't want to fill information with full library which is quite long.

I created a library in PHP with Symfony framework for cURL with following Idea.

```
class Request {
    store single request information
}

class Requests {
callback = null
timeout = 45
window=5

headers = [some pre-defined headers for all requests]
options = [some pre-defined cURL options for all requests]
params = [] // need to pass to callback function some values to process
requests = [] // store Request Objects
set_callback(call_back)
get(url, headers, options, params) // internally call request method with default GET as method and empty post_data
post(url, post_data, headers, options, params) // internally call request method with default POST as method
request(url, method, post_data, headers, options, params) {
   $this->requests = new Request(url, method, post_data, headers, options, params)
}

private single_curl() {
  response = curl()
  if (callable) {
    $rs = call_user_func($response, $request)
    yield from $rs;
    $rs->getReturn();
  }

}
private multi_curl(window) // similar implementation as single_curl but with window, window determine how many parallel requests to run
execute(window=5) // it determine whether to run single_curl or multi_curl
}
```

usage:

```
$requests = new Requests()
//add any number of requests
// optional
$requests->set_callback(callback);
$requests->get(...params);
$requests->post(...params); //
$gen = $requests->execute();
loop $gen to process
```

it works great in PHP. so I want to do same in Python

Here is the thing I could not find in Python after googling and checking in youtube for few days.

1. There are many which gives power to call single requests like **requests, urllib, urllib2, httplib** but only **pycurl** acts like proper curl function with option of **multi_curl**

Is there any better library which suits my requirements. suggestion is appreciated.

2.For 90% of developers normal curl, multiCurl do the trick but I do want to implement with generators only.
reason is, this are some third party API where I need to call more than half million requests. so I do not want **Memory Exhaustion** issue to pop out and make me unnecessary burden to continue from where it left out.

3. Main and Important one, I could achieve my requirement if I give some more time, but I could not find, **how to differentiate yield and return in Python**

Please be generous in providing sample code which could satisfy my requirement, even if there is some setback is of no problem. I can change it to my requirements.